# Trace of power of stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

I would like to know if this statement is true.
Having a stochastic matrix (rows sum up to 1), with a positive (non-negative) diagonal, then it holds that
$$\text{trace}({W^2})\leq \text{trace}({W}),$$
(or more generally, if $p\geq q$, then $\text{trace}({W^p})\leq \text{trace}({W}^q)$.)

In other words, does it hold that $\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_i^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_i$ ? Note that $\lambda_i$ may be also negative (it is not a positive-definite, or symmetric matrix)!

My intuition says it should hold, since with the powers of a stochastic matrix ${W}$, the spectrum gets smaller and smaller, eventually leading to $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_i=0$, for $i\ne 1$. But is also the SUM of eigenvalues getting smaller with growing power? Thanks.

Comment: @Lost1 Sorry Lost1. You were just too fast for me:)..which I btw. really appreciate.

Comment: nevertheless, it is still false, change the $0$ to a small $\epsilon$.

Comment: An obvious comment: Note that your inequality is equivalent to the eigenvalues satisfying $\sum_i \lambda_i (1-\lambda_i)\geq 0$ and so will certainly be true when all eigenvalues are between 0 and 1. One may expect this not to be 'strict', I.e. the inequality can still hold if the eigenvalues are slightly outside this interval; but it eventually will fail.

Comment: Also, since 1 is always an eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix, this criterion is in fact strict for the 2x2 case e.g. the case by @Lost1.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks. Yes, that is the trivial case. But what if some eigenvalues are negative (but still smaller than 1 in absolute value)?

Comment: That's what I was getting at with my 'strict' comment. And my second point is just that you'll have to go to at least the 3x3 case to get something nontrivial.

Comment: @Semiclassical I agree. It definitely gets more interesting for $N>2$. From simulations for arbitrary $N>2 $, I always get the result.. Unfortunately I can't find anything relevant in literature which would support it.

Comment: It also makes sense that you need more than two states since the two state case generically has one site becoming dominant over time. But if you've got at least three then you can get more interesting dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

This is (still) trivially false if you just take a small epsilon

$p_{12}=p_{21}=1-\epsilon$ and $p_{11}=p_{22}=\epsilon$

The trace of $P^2$ is $2((1-\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2)>2\epsilon$, if take $\epsilon$ to be, say, smaller than 0.2

Comment: Thanks. Of course. Please, see the edited post. I assume that the diagonal is positive (possibly non-negative).

Comment: you are essentially asking how does the overall probability that a state remains where it is in 1 move compare with a state remains where it is in 2 moves...

Comment: I did some simulation of your example and I find it very very interesting:
http://postimg.org/image/t3m7svo6v/

where I plotted trace for various $\epsilon$ for various powers ($1,2,3,4,19,20$). Clearly, if $\epsilon>0.5$ then "my claim" holds for any power. For $\epsilon<0.5$ it does not. Maybe the row-stochastic matrix must be further diagonally dominant?

Comment: For matrix 
$P=\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon & 1-\epsilon & 0\\ 1-\epsilon & \epsilon & 0\\ 1-\epsilon & 0 &\epsilon\end{pmatrix}$
I get the following behavior:
http://postimg.org/image/anl2de1fr/

Clearly, there is again some $\epsilon$ from which higher it holds.

Comment: @pisoir so what are you trying to show?

Comment: Now, I am trying to find additional conditions on stochastic matrices for which $\text{trace} (W^2)\leq \text{trace} (W)$. I thought that one of such conditions could be that if the $\text{trace}(W)>1$, then it holds. But I found a counterexample which shows that this is not sufficient.